# Does "do" v. "jutsu" naming reflect Daoist influence?

Tags: history, style, japanese, mentality

I have read about the naming changes in Japanese martial arts, with a shift from *jutsu* (術) to *do* (道) reflecting a supposed shift in emphasis from fighting techniques to a quest for mental and physical perfection.

> Kano followed the lead of the founder of the Jikishin Ryu in making the transition from *jutsu* form, primarily concerned with martial matters, to a *do* form, where emphasis is on character development and the perfection of the individual.

From p. 21 of *Judo Formal Techniques* by Tadao Otaki and Donn F. Draeger, Tuttle Publishing, Boston, 1983.

For example:

1. jujutsu -> judo
2. kenjutsu -> kendo
3. aikijutsu -> aikido

Asian-influenced martial arts today commonly share this mindset that martial arts are not solely about fighting. Included are styles that definitely predate the Japanese naming shift, such as *taijiquan*, which claims [Daoist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoism) (道) influence.

Is the Japanese name shift also a Daoist influence? If so, why does this Daoist influence in the martial arts take so long to reach Japan?

Comment: This question is posted as part of the [current question challenge](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/598/5961).

Comment: I believe it is more Shinto than Daoist

Comment: Japan isn't the only country who's martial arts have "do" in it, such as Korea, which has TaekwanDO and HapkiDO, and I believe that there is such thing as Hapkijitsu, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Related: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/whats-the-difference-between-iaijutsu-and-iaido https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/676/what-are-the-key-differences-between-kendo-and-kenjutsu https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9578/what-did-judo-change-innovate-when-it-branched-from-jujutsu